# Finding mean of those values in column B who reside in rows having one of the K largest elements in Column A: Pandas Dataframe GroupBy Object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a panda dataframe, call it **df1**, with many columns (col1, col2, ...)

I want to group the data on two particular columns - say **col4** and **col7**

In each group, I want to find the **top K values in col9**.

Then, I want to find the **mean of values in col10**, ***which satisfy the condition of having the top K values in col9.***

I attempted to solve it as shown below:

```
consideredCols = ['col4', 'col7']
k_value = 3
grp_data = df1.groupby(consideredCols)
print(grp_data.apply(lambda grp: (grp.col9.nlargest(k_value)).mean('col10')))
```

Example: (showing after the groupby ['col4', 'col7'] phase)

```
                col9    col10
col4    col7        
john    doe        5    12
                   4    15
                  11    9
                   4    14


jane    doe       42    421
                  50    42
                 124    27
                  15    25
```

if K=2 here, then I want the result as (12+9)/2 for John and (42+27)/2 for Jane.

Comment: Can you add data sample and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close - need [`DataFrame.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) for not lose column `col10` and then get `mean`:

```
grp_data = df1.groupby(consideredCols)
print(grp_data.apply(lambda grp: (grp.nlargest(k_value, 'col9'))['col10'].mean()))

col4  col7
jane  doe     34.5
john  doe     10.5
dtype: float64
```

Another solution with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
out = (df1.sort_values(['col4','col7','col9'], ascending=[True, True, False])
              .groupby(consideredCols)
              .apply(lambda grp: grp.head(2)['col10'].mean()))
print (out)

col4  col7
jane  doe     34.5
john  doe     10.5
dtype: float64
```

---

```
out = (df1.sort_values(['col4','col7','col9'], ascending=[True, True, False])
              .groupby(consideredCols)
              .apply(lambda grp: grp.head(2)['col10'].mean())).mean()
print (out)
22.5
```

For better understanding functions with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) is the best create custom function and use `print`s, then is possible rewrite it with lambda functions:

```
consideredCols = ['col4', 'col7']
k_value = 2

def f(grp):
     print (grp)

     print (grp.nlargest(k_value, 'col9'))
     print (grp.nlargest(k_value, 'col9')['col10'].mean())

     return grp.nlargest(k_value, 'col9')['col10'].mean()

grp_data = df1.groupby(consideredCols)
print(grp_data.apply(f))
```

Comment: Thank you! One more thing, if I now want to find the mean of 34.5 and 10.5 also, in the sense that I want to apply mean over these results we just found, how should I do that?

Comment: Only add `.mean()` to the end ;)

Comment: Thanks! New to panda dataframes! Had trouble understanding how to handle these GroupBy objects of dataframe.

Comment: Ok, give me a sec.

Comment: Thank you! this is perfect.